# Is it possible to create a safe API for public editable data with MongoLabs?

Tags: rest, mlab

This is related to [Is there ReadOnly REST API key to a MongoLab database, or is it always ReadWrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250145/is-there-readonly-rest-api-key-to-a-mongolab-database-or-is-it-always-readwrite?rq=1) and [How does Mongolab REST API authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276146/how-does-mongolab-rest-api-authenticate?rq=1)

I want to make it possible for unauthenticated users of my web app to create resources and share them. The created resource is an array of links `['link1', 'link2', 'link3']`.

I'm looking at using MongoLabs directly from the client for this, which is possible through their [REST api](https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-REST-API-for-MongoDB).

The problem though is that as far as I can see, if I do that, it would be impossible to prevent vandalists to clear out the entire collection rather easily.

Is this correct, and if so, is there a simple solution (without running a custom backend) to do something like this?

Comment: why the downvotes? seems like an honest question to me... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No idea; also think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you could create a "history", so if something goes wrong you can call on an easy command to restore records.
Secondly you might screen connected clients for abusive behavior; eg measure the number of delete or update commands in a certain timeset. If this get triggered you can call on your restoration process.

Note; i have no experience with MongoLabs whatsoever, but this - to me - would be a suitable safeguard in creating a public api.

Comment: You're right about the need to protect a public api your ideas are not bad either. However, I would like to use MongoLab directly from the client. It seems that if you do that you cannot safeguard against someone emptying _all_ your  collections with curl...

Comment: My guess it's a drawback of using someone else's system. Perhaps you can lob the question over to mongolab's support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276146/how-does-mongolab-rest-api-authenticate?rq=1 ?